# "MissingSchemaError" when seeding database using mongoose-seeder

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am attempting to seed a database using mongoose-seeder, and I keep getting a MissingSchemaError. I am sure that I am setting up the schema properly, so I am lost as to why this is happening.
The file where I set up the schema looks like this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const UserSchema = new Schema({
 fullName: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
 trim: true
 },
 emailAddress: {
  type: String,
 unique: true,
 required: true,
 match: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)| . 
(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA- 
 Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
},
password: {
 type: String,
 required: true
}
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.User = User;
```

and in my main file:

```
'use strict';

// load modules
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const seeder = require('mongoose-seeder');
const data = require('./data/data.json');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();


//set up database connection
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/courseapi");
const db = mongoose.connection;

//handle err connecting to db
db.on("error", (err) => console.error("Error connecting to database: ", 
err));

//success
db.once("open", () => {
  console.log("Connected to database");
  seeder.seed(data, {dropDatabase: false}).then(function(dbData){
      console.log("Database seeded!");
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.error("Error seeding database", err);
  })
});
```

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Normally, you would require the schema to be loaded first before the router or main file is loaded. In order to use the User schema, think you would need to require the same in the main file. Also, kindly provide the sample of `data.json` that you are attempting to seed.

Answer (score 0):

The `mongoose-seeder` package is not maintained. Hence suggesting an alternative to import data. You can populate MongoDB in the CLI (command line interface) using `mongoimport`.It will load a JSON file into a specified MongoDB Instance & Collection. All you need is a `mongod` instance to be running before execution.

Please go through the [walkthrough](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/shell/import-data/).

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help! The project required using a module to seed the data, so I ended up using mongoose-seed instead. (Required some reformatting of the json, but thankfully the file was relatively small)

Answer (score 0):

it's better to use the actively maintained [Seedgoose](https://github.com/zhangkaiyulw/seedgoose). It's the ultimate mongoose seeder with smart reference support.